# How does sodium rosinate enhances lathering property?

Tags: biochemistry, solutions, chemical-biology

Why don't we use sodium carbonate or sodium stearate? What does sodium rosinate contain that the other two don't?

Comment: It is hard to understand how you might think of sodium carbonate versus sodium stereate as alternatives. Rosinate and stereate are detergents, carbonate is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rosin acids, or more commonly, resin acids, are more complicated structures that are able to protect an air bubble mechanically. Abietic acid, a common resin acid, looks like a platey structure with more strength than a linear chain like stearate or oleate, two other common soap anions.

[image]

In fact, resin acids were, and still are, used very commonly to maintain a stable air content in concrete, to minimize freeze-thaw damage. Ordinary surfactants would give unpredictable air content: either too low because the fine particles of cement broke the air bubbles, or too high because there was so much surfactant  that it overwhelmed the fine particle disruptions.

Some synthetic foam stabilizers are polymeric anions or have other strong intermolecular attractions.